# Почему post становится get?

Tags: html, django, post, get

Пишу отправку сообщений на Django сервере и столкнулся с такой проблемой: при нажатии на **input** типа **submit** в форме типа **post** происходит передача методом **GET**. Как это возможно и как это можно поправить?
Вот код:

```
<form method="post" id="form-callback" class="contact__form" action="/mail/">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="contact__line">
         <input type="text" class="contact__input contact__input-1" name="mail_name" placeholder="Ваше имя">
         <input type="email" class="contact__input contact__input-1" name="mail_email" placeholder="Email для ответа">
    </div>
    <div class='contact__area'>
        <textarea class="contact__input" placeholder="Текст вопроса" name="mail_text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input class="contact__button" type="submit" value="Отправить">
```

Вот серверный код(запрос приходит):

```
@csrf_exempt
def mail_post(request):

if request.method == 'POST':

    mail_email = request.POST.get('mail_email', '')
    mail_name = request.POST.get('mail_name', '')
    mail_text = request.POST.get('mail_text', '')


    return HttpResponse(JsonResponse(mail_email + " " + mail_name + " " + mail_text + " " + request.method).content)

    try:
        sendMail(mail_email, mail_name, mail_text)
    except BadHeaderError:
        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')

return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

Comment: Как вы определяете, что приходит GET?

Comment: @andreymal через DEBUG = TRUE в settings.py и ответам сервера на мои действия

Comment: А чуть-чуть конкретнее? Что именно вы такое увидели, что решили, что это GET?

Comment: Изначально при любом запросе я выводил тип запроса. Т.е. я через HttpResponse выдавал request.method. Далее, при включенном DEBUG = TRUE при каких-либо ошибках писалась вся информация о запросе: локальные переменные, места ошибок и тд + вместе с этим приходили данные о запросе(post/get)

Comment: В моей джанге ваш DEBUG = TRUE показывает очень даже POST. Воспроизведите проблему в отдельном пустом проекте, приведите [mcve], потому что сейчас ваша форма, которую вы привели в тексте вопроса, отправляет не GET, а вполне POST (и код у меня падает на строчке `return HttpResponse(JsonResponse` которая выполняется только для POST-запроса)

Comment: А что может влиять, чтобы становился GET запрос?

Comment: Абсолютно что угодно, от кривого джаваскрипта до вашей банальной невнимательности. Но в том коде, который вы привели, никаких поводов для отправки GET-запроса нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/ru/mail/ в action и будет тебе счастье ;)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]